# Jsoup and same mismatch error for grabbing HTML

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I tried my own one already grabbing html from wikis main page like the suggested sample on JSoup.org but I got a similar error when I was trying to print it out using a simple for loop/ It was saying you cant use.size on Elements.

```
      for(int d=1; d<= newsHeadlines.size(); d++)
```

Then I tried an example that was posted here and I get this error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.jsoup.select.Elements to javax.lang.model.util.Elements

Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
  at grabdatafromHTML.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Not sure why I get this error for the code down below and help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks :)

```
package grabdatafromHTML;

import java.util.List;

import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;

import org.jsoup.select.*; 
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping";  

        // Download the HTML and store in a Document
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        // Select the <p> Elements from the document    
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");

        // For each selected <p> element, print out its text
        for (Element e : paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }   



}
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("some error");
    }
}


   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the import

```
import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;
```

to allow the class `org.jsoup.select.Elements` to be used (which you've already imported)